# Expired queries and appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Within a task, I'm iterating over a collection of items with a query. After each entity is fetched from the query, I am also performing a URL request. After iterating over a large number of these items, I'm seeing the following error:

```
BadRequestError: The requested query has expired. Please restart it with the last cursor to read more results.
```

What is the lease on a query once you create it?

Answer (score 7):

This issue might shed some light on your problem: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4432

> Even though offline requests can currently live up to 10 minutes (and
>   background instances can live forever) datastore queries can still
>   only live for 30 seconds. We plan to improve this, but since a
>   'consistent' view of the data is only preserved for a limit period of
>   time, there is an upper bound to how long a query can last (which is <
>   10 minutes).

...

> Instead of running a single long query, consider fetching batches from
>   the query using query cursors.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple helper to do this - you call it with the batch_size, the object class for the query, and the callback that handles the elements in the query.

(Note, I am using djangoappengine and therefore django query format - but you could modify it to suit.)

```
def loop_over_objects_in_batches(batch_size, object_class, callback):
    logging.info("Calling batched loop with batch_size: %d, object_class: %s, callback: %s" % (batch_size, object_class, callback))

    num_els = object_class.objects.all().count()
    num_loops = num_els / batch_size
    remainder = num_els - num_loops * batch_size
    offset = 0
    while offset < num_loops * batch_size:
        logging.info("Processing batch (%d:%d)" % (offset, offset+batch_size))
        query = object_class.objects.all()[offset:offset + batch_size]
        for q in query:
            callback(q)

        offset = offset + batch_size

    if remainder:
        logging.info("Processing remainder batch (%d:-)" % offset)
        query = object_class.objects.all()[offset:]
        for q in query:
            callback(q)
```

Comment: There was no need to count() and explicitly work out the remainder - the [:] slice will return a remainder query and you could detect that in the loop and break out when so. I wrote it explicitly like this to be clear what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple create defered tasks for each element in your sequence. There is good article with examples how to do it right way "[Background work with the deferred library](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html)".